# Re-render the screen when an object changes

Tags: c#, maui

I would like to slightly modify the code generated when creating a maui project to implement the following

1. add an object to Meetings in MainPage.xaml.cs when the button is clicked
2. display the contents of that Meetings

I wrote the following code for this purpose, but there is no change in the output content. One possible reason for this is that adding data to the object does not re-render the screen. How can I solve this problem?

`Views/MainPage.xaml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App.Views"
             x:Class="App.Views.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"

            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Meetings}" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

`Views/MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
namespace App.Views;

using App.Models;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
        int count = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
                InitializeComponent();
                BindingContext = new Models.AllMeetings();
        }

        private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                count++;

                if (count == 1)
                        CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
                else
                        CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";

                SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);

        ((Models.AllMeetings)BindingContext).Meetings.Add(new Models.Meeting() { Name = "foo" });
        }
}
```

`Modes/AllMeetings`

```
namespace App.Models;

internal class AllMeetings
{
    public List<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }
}
```

`Models/Meetings.cs`

```
namespace App.Models;

internal class Meeting
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

## Updates

`Models/AllMeetings.cs`

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace ailia_speech_gui.Models;

internal class AllMeetings
{
    public ObservableCollection<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }

    public void Add_Meeting(Meeting meeting)
    {
        this.Meetings.Add(meeting);
    }

}
```

Comment: use an `ObservableCollection`, not a `List`

Comment: @Jason Thank you for comment. I changed `AllMeetings` List to `ObservableCollection` but still View is not updated

Comment: you have also not supplies any template for your `ListView`

Comment: @Jason I understood from this tutorial that only the type name is displayed after binding in this way, am I wrong? https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/data-binding-basics?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: where are you initializing `Meetings`?

Comment: @Jason `((Models.AllMeetings)BindingContext).Meetings.Add(new Models.Meeting() { Name = "foo" });
        }`

Comment: Is it possible to do print debugging, etc. with MAUI?

Comment: That is adding a meeting to the collection, not instantiating the collection itself.  You can use Console.WriteLine to output to the log

Comment: If you add a test meeting in the VM constructor does it show?

Comment: @Jason I am new to MAUI and do not know what a VM constructor is.

Comment: Is it not an error to do `Add` with the collection uninitialized?

Comment: VM is ViewModel.  And yes you will get an exception if you add an item to a null collection.  That is why I have repeatedly asked where you are initializing it

Answer (score 1):

Meetings collection must be somewhere initialized before calling any operation on collestion (be it on property level or in constructor):

```
public class AllMeetings
{
    public ObservableCollection<Meeting> Meetings { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Meeting>(); 

    public void Add_Meeting(Meeting meeting)
    {
        this.Meetings.Add(meeting);
    }
}
```

And ListView must have some data template to tell UI how data should be presented:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Meetings}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation along with your code please

Comment: This code generates the `ViewCell` itself, but does not display the `Text`. I also see that this code seems to work fine, why do you think this is?

Answer (score 1):

I made a demo on my side. You can refer to my demo to change your project.

Here is the code in my `Model` named Products.cs:

```
namespace ListViewDelete.Models
{
    public class Products
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public double Price
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to create a viewmodel to realize the delete and add method and create the ObservableCollection to load the data.

Here is the code in my `ViewModel`:

```
namespace ListViewDelete.ViewModels
{
    internal class ProductsViewModels
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Products> Products
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public Command<Products> RemoveCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command<Products>((Product) => {
                    Products.Remove(Product);
                });
            }
        }

        public Command<Products> AddCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command<Products>((Product) => {
                    Products.Add(Product);
                });
            }
        }
        public ProductsViewModels()
        {
            Products = new ObservableCollection<Products> {
                new Products {
                    Name = "name1",
                        Price = 100
                },
                new Products {
                    Name = "name2",
                        Price = 100
                },
                new Products {
                    Name = "name3",
                        Price = 100
                }
            
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Last, you need to create the `ListView` or the `CollectionView` in the MainPage.xaml. Here is the code in the MainPage.xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
        <Button Text="add" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Price}" />
                        <Button Text="Remove" Clicked="Remove_Clicked" />
                    </StackLayout>
                
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
 </StackLayout>
```

Here is the code in MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
   namespace ListViewDelete
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // bind the viewmodel to the Mainpage
            BindingContext = new ProductsViewModels();
        }

        //delete the item from the observablecollection
        public void Remove_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var button = sender as Button;
            var product = button.BindingContext as Products;
            var vm = BindingContext as ProductsViewModels;
            vm.RemoveCommand.Execute(product);
        }

        //add the new item to the observablecollection
        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var product = new Products()
            {
                Name =" new name",
                Price = 100
            };
            var vm = BindingContext as ProductsViewModels;
            vm.AddCommand.Execute(product);
        }
    }
}
```